# How to duplicate a row via Ecto if a model has associations?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a model which has several "belongs_to" and "has_many"
I want to duplicate it with a newly generated  "id" and with a new value of some other field.

```
m1 = Repo.get(MyModel, 123)
|> Map.delete(:id)

m2 = Repo.insert!(m1, %{my_field: "aaa"})
# or
# m2 = Repo.insert!(MyModel.changeset(m1, %{my_field: "aaa"}))
```

and error:

```
(RuntimeError) attempting to cast or change association `my_assoc1` from `MyModel` that was not loaded. 
Please preload your associations before manipulating them through changesets
```

I don't want to have to preload each association. 
Besides, why would I have to if I want a duplicated model instance to have `my_assoc1_id`, which is an integer, identical to the original instance, that is, whether or not the association is loaded shouldn't matter.

Neither would I want to have to remove each association from a changset.

How to do it?

Comment: You should go full path through [`Ecto.Changeset`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html?) for the new record.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, why?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin see my update in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** manipulate/cast associations like `belongs_to` or `has_many` directly. These associations are an abstraction layer so that you can manipulate data easier.

For example:

```
schema "my_model" do
    belongs_to :my_field, Example
end
```

If you take a look in the database or migration, you can notice that a field called `my_field_id` was created, containing the foreign key pointing to the other table.

If you want to clone a entity with all associations, you just create a changeset that makes sure that foreign keys get casted too:

```
def changeset(my_model, params \\ %{}) do
    user
    |> cast(params, [:my_field_id])
    |> validate_required([:my_field_id])
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:my_field_id)
  end
```

Comment: I don't want to manipulate an association, you haven't understood my question

Comment: it is the same in this context, you tried to cast it.